# Connect Cables in pc and it’s affect

Tags: iphone, software

Is there anyway I can know if the cable I use to charge my phone in it was connect to my pc before or not? Is there something in pc can let me see that because my pc contain some malware and spy files that comes to it through another phone because I used to use all cables and connect them to pc so I decided to format my other iphone in charger while charging it in the wall during deleting your data and setting the phone turned off so I connect it to the charger and it start to format and delete all data and settings while connect to charger so I format it again and I am afraid that the malware will be inside the iPhone system and even formatting it will no help

Comment: Bro,i got a stroke while reading this.

Comment: Malware cannot propogate through a standard charging cable

Comment: you are still not using sentences...

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to know the history of a cable (sad news).

But, good news, a charging cable cannot be used to propagate malware whatever its history (the malware can be inside the devices at each side of the cable but not INSIDE the cable)

An exception could be a specific gear, crafted by a hacker, to look like a charging cable but with some minimal computing capabilities (like this kind of gears whose take the appearance of common computer tools : https://shop.hak5.org/collections/sale/products/lan-turtle).
You can be confident with the fact that no one will use it against you until you start to store very sensitive data (like being employed at boeing) or have a hacker friend who like jokes.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question, your PC was or maybe still is infected with malware.

Your assumption that your PC was infected just because you connected another phone to it may be wrong. AFAIK malware doesen't just spread from iOS to other operating systems just by connecting them with a USB cable. And if your PC is infected I doubt it's going to spread to another iOS device just by plugging it in.

But I would check your PC and remove the malware (maybe even reinstall your OS).